# Insert multiple table and row in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying insert data into multiple table and multiple row in single form, I have two table **pms_service_fee** and **pms_service_fee_detail**, At this point when user submit the form the data will go to both tables.

My Model

```
function add_pms($data)
{

        $data = escape_array($data);

        $pms_data = [
            'unit_id'   => $data['unit_id'],
        ];

        if(isset($data['edit_pms_id'])) {
            $this->db->set($pms_data)->where('id', $data['edit_pms_id'])->update('pms_service_fee');
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('pms_service_fee', $pms_data);
        }

        $pms_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

> ```
>         // I have this array, But is not a good idea because I want that array in loop. But I don't know how.
> ```

```
        $pms_service_fee_detail = [
            [
                'pms_id'   => $pms_id,
                'pms_service_fee_id' => $data['pms_service_fee_id'][0],
                'pms_service_fee_price' => $data['pms_service_fee_price'][0],
            ],
            [
                'pms_id'   => $pms_id,
                'pms_service_fee_id' => $data['pms_service_fee_id'][1],
                'pms_service_fee_price' => $data['pms_service_fee_price'][1],
            ],
        ];

        $this->db->insert_batch('pms_service_fee_detail', $pms_service_fee_detail); 
}
```

Comment: Using for loop you can push your array to `$pms_service_fee_detail` and out side the loop use it for batch insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the loop to push the array into the array something like below.

```
$data = escape_array($data);

        $pms_data = [
            'unit_id'   => $data['unit_id'],
        ];

        if(isset($data['edit_pms_id'])) {
            $this->db->set($pms_data)->where('id', $data['edit_pms_id'])->update('pms_service_fee');
        } else {
            $this->db->insert('pms_service_fee', $pms_data);
        }

        $pms_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $pms_service_fee_detail = [];

        / * Your Loop Here to Push the values to the array */
        foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {

             $pms_service_fee_detail[] = [
               'pms_id'   => $pms_id,
               'pms_service_fee_id' => $yourArray[$key]['pms_service_fee_id'],
               'pms_service_fee_price' => $yourArray[$key]['pms_service_fee_price'],
             ];
        }

$this->db->insert_batch('pms_service_fee_detail', $pms_service_fee_detail);
```

Comment: Thanks, I try this solution but it seems it only insert to the first table pms_service_fee.

Comment: @leanghy , You can make the array according to your requirement, actually your array was unclear to me just because you used `$data['pms_service_fee_id'][0]` , I could gave you better solution if I can see the request params.